# Execute word add-in on current docx file

Tags: c#, ms-word, add-in

I created Word add-in and want to execute it on the current Word file instead of using the file Path on disk. How I can refer to the Active Document ?

I'm now using the file Path like this :

```
string Filepath= @"D:\Word-addins\Example\Test.docx";
```

and how I can determine the Active file path to save the result on the same path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word Add-In, the current document is simply `ThisDocument`.

You will have to generate this class yourself (as it derives from `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.DocumentBase`) as explained here:

- [Programming Document-Level Customizations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386206.aspx)

Try to understand the **[Word Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kw65a0we.aspx)** to know how to work with text in the current document, stuff like this.Selection etc.

There is even a tutorial on [how to create your first document level Add-In](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc442985.aspx).